# How to paginate in spring ldap using skip value

Tags: java, spring-ldap, opendj

Can any body help me on how I can find some record from LDAP using springldap.

My problem is, I have created a rest service and it accepts some parameter. One is offset and another is limit. Offset parameter escape some record like if my ldap server have 500 record. 
Now if I give offset value 1 and LIMIT is 100. then it should give first 100 record from ldap.
If I give offset value 100 and LIMIT is 100, then it should give 100 record after first 100 record from ldap.
If I give offset value 50 and LIMIT is 10, then it should give 10 record after first 50 record from ldap.

I am stuck on how to set offset value in spring ldap template. I have set limit value and it is working fine.

I am sharing peace of code.

```
public OrganisationGroups getOrganisationGroup() 
{

    SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();

    controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    controls.setCountLimit(MAXIMUM_SEARCH_GROUP_COUNT);
    AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
    filter.and(new EqualsFilter("objectclass", "groupOfUniqueNames"));
    List<OrganisationGroup> organisationGroup = ldapTemplate.search("", filter.toString(), controls, new GroupSearchMapper());

    OrganisationGroups groups = new OrganisationGroups();
    groups.setOrganisationGroup(organisationGroup);
    groups.setCount(organisationGroup.size());
    return groups;
}
```

In this code I have set MAXIMUM_SEARCH_GROUP_COUNT variable to find out maximum record from ldap. But I am not able to set parameter or any other way to escape some records from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use the Virtual List View request control (link to [specification](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-ldapext-ldapv3-vlv-09.txt)) also known as VLV. Note that to use VLV, you will need to make configuration changes on your LDAP server (I assume you are using OpenDJ, which supports [VLV](https://forgerock.org/opendj/doc/bootstrap/admin-guide/index.html#indexes-vlv)).

There is a code example for JNDI LDAP provider with the VLV request control at this [forum](http://www.forumeasy.com/forums/thread.jsp?tid=123930528133&fid=ldapprof2&highlight=Virtual%20List%20View%20Control%20Code%20Example).